# Selling programming language courses - copyright issues?

Tags: copyright

Are there any copyright problems in selling courses (in PDF format) online and in real life, on a programming language linked to a particular company?

My concern is with the VBA language, linked to Excel (and so Microsoft). Can I use their logo? Screen captures?

Comment: There are lots of third party companies that offer training for various company's products, and in general as far as they're concerned 'the more the merrier'.  In short, they will bend over backwards to help.  Generally they want to review your course content to make sure you're 'covering all the bases'.  The best thing to do is get hold of a live body inside the company and get their advice directly.

Answer (score 6):

Logo and any visual material (videos, manuals) provided by such company will be surely protected by copyright law. You should ask them on what conditions you can use such materials (their logo, their videos, their manuals or excerpts from videos and manuals).

By the way if you dont have MS certification in there areas, they might be reluctant to give you permissions to use their visual materials...

EDIT: I found [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/Permissions/default.aspx) that could help evaluate conditions for using MS copyrighted content:

Comment: Do you happen to know where I could ask the permission ?

Comment: I found this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/Permissions/default.aspx - I dont know if everything you need is there, but it could help you. There is a ton of information on conditions for using their copyrighted material

Comment: I have seen that, the answer seems to be yes for both logos and screens !